# xml2Json method returns Undefined object in Postman

Tags: undefined, postman

I am using Postman to test a `HTTP-POST` request that uses `XML` format. The response body comes fine in the Postman Window with 200 Success response.

However when I am trying to extract a node value from response using `xml2Json` method, it is returning a Undefined object. I tried to find if anyone faced similar issue , but did not find any.

Below is the Test Script.

Test :

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
console.log("jsonObject is : ",jsonObject);


==============
Console Output:
jsonObject is :  undefined

Response example:
--uuid:960b8c52-9c48-4302-b7d6-88a21828a01a
Content-Id: 
<rootpart*960b8c52-9c48-4302-b7d6-88a21828a01a@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <S:Body>
            <ns2:setFavoriteResponse xmlns:ns2="http://confidential">
                <favoriteID>25316981</favoriteID>
            </ns2:setFavoriteResponse>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
--uuid:960b8c52-9c48-4302-b7d6-88a21828a01a--
```

Comment: I have realized that the response contains header part that is not usually displayed in SOAP UI.--uuid:f5e69f1f-3d1d-4c71-9d33-021c02cfb5f0
Content-Id: 
<rootpart*f5e69f1f-3d1d-4c71-9d33-021c02cfb5f0@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

Answer (score 3):

I write here my answer, maybe it will help others.

I got the same undefined when using `xml2Json(responseBody)`.

In my case the `responseBody` had an **invalid xml**.

As another use case when `xml2Json(responseBody)` can be undefined is, as you commented, the `responseBody` can contain other parts besides the xml.